# bootstrap table template not match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am trying to replicate this template and use this table as my startup, but if I am going to copy the code then result will not have the same output.

This is my reference table template:
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/pagination/

Here are my current copied code putting all together on my index.cshtml:

```
<head>

    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>


<body>
    <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="th-sm">
                    Name

                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">
                    Position

                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">
                    Office

                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">
                    Age

                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">
                    Start date

                </th>
                <th class="th-sm">
                    Salary

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>          
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Position
                </th>
                <th>
                    Office
                </th>
                <th>
                    Age
                </th>
                <th>
                    Start date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Salary
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
        $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
    });

</script>
```

The output should be something like this:
[image]

But from my output it doesn't have any pagination, limit drop down and search bar. It is just a plain table:
[image]

Is there any items that I am missing. TIA

Comment: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/pagination/
`Note: This integration is available from version 4.5.7 (released 16.07.2018).` and you are using `4.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this at bottom of your page with other scripts

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
```

And add this on top of your page where you are adding css files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

And it will work

Answer (score 0):

You are using only `Bootstrap`.

You have to use `MDBootstrap CSS` and `DataTable CSS` also.

Add these links to your webpage:

https://mdbootstrap.com/md-bootstrap-cdn/

In this below link go to Getting Started Tab. You will get those `Datatable` links also. Their datatable is different from natural datatable. So, If you download their code and paste the link it will work fine.

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the css and js for `MDBootstrap` not just the bootstrap alone